# C code structure evokes linking cycles with CMake

Tags: c, makefile, build, linker, cmake

I am trying to build bozorth3 from NIST Biometric Image Software using CMake but having troubles with the linking. This software has on the one side an executable:

```c
//bin/bozorth3.c:
int min_comp_minutiae = MIN_COMP_BOZORTH_MINUTIAE; // defines what libbozorth needs
//...
getopt_spec = malloc_or_exit( (int)strlen(default_getopt_spec) + 1,
                              "getopt() string" ); // uses a function from libbozorth
```

...on the other side a library:

```c
//lib/bozorth3.c:
if ( pstruct->nrows < min_computable_minutiae ) { //uses a variable defined in bin

//lib/bz_alloc.c:
char * malloc_or_exit( int nbytes,
                       const char * what ) { // implements a function used in bin
  //code
}
```

...and a common header:

```c
//include/bozorth3.h
extern int min_comp_minutiae;
extern char *malloc_or_exit(int, const char *);
```

With the following filesets (exceprt from CMakeLists.txt)

```
set(LIB_SOURCE_FILES
        src/lib/bozorth3/bozorth3.c
        src/lib/bozorth3/bz_alloc.c #[[etc...]])
add_library(libbozorth3 ${LIB_SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(bozorth3 src/bin/bozorth3/bozorth3.c)
```

Since the executable uses the library I have to add a link: `target_link_libraries(bozorth3 libbozorth3)`. But this is results in an error:

```
Linking C shared library ..\..\bin\liblibbozorth3.dll
CMakeFiles\libbozorth3.dir/objects.a(bozorth3.c.obj):bozorth3.c:(.rdata$.refptr.min_computable_minutiae[.refptr.min_computable_minutiae]+0x0): undefined reference to `min_computable_minutiae'
```

It forces me to create a link vice-versa: `target_link_libraries(libbozorth3 bozorth3)` and overriding [`ENABLE_EXPORTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/ENABLE_EXPORTS.html), which of course results in an error as well:

```
Linking C executable ..\..\bin\bozorth3.exe
CMakeFiles\bozorth3.dir/objects.a(bozorth3.c.obj): In function `main':
D:/git/ba-phmf/NBIS/bozorth3/src/bin/bozorth3/bozorth3.c:174: undefined reference to `malloc_or_exit'
```

And I cant have both because it obviously results in a cycle:

```
CMake Error: The inter-target dependency graph contains the following strongly connected component (cycle):
  "libbozorth3" of type SHARED_LIBRARY
    depends on "bozorth3" (weak)
  "bozorth3" of type EXECUTABLE
    depends on "libbozorth3" (weak)
At least one of these targets is not a STATIC_LIBRARY.  Cyclic dependencies are allowed only among static libraries.
```

I can compile the package using the original makefiles but need to "translate" it into CMake in order to have integration into my project. I tried to analyze the makefiles but couldn't find a solution. The whole package can be found at [github](https://github.com/lessandro/nbis/tree/master/bozorth3).

I am using CLion 2016.2.3, CMake 3.7.0-rc2, Msys2 20160921 with GCC 6.2.0 and ld 2.27 on Windows 7 Professional N x64

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
add_library(libbozorth3 STATIC ${LIB_SOURCE_FILES})
set_property(TARGET libbozorth3 PROPERTY OUTPUT_NAME bozorth3)
target_include_directories(libbozorth3 PRIVATE
        include)

add_executable(bozorth3 ${BIN_SOURCE_FILEs})
target_include_directories(bozorth3 PRIVATE
        include)
target_link_libraries(bozorth3
        PRIVATE
        libbozorth3
        commonnbis)
```